# cashfree payment gateway not returning any data after successful payment

Tags: php

i am using cashfree payment gateway in my website (using php sdk of cashfree payment gateway) , its working fine on local but on upload to server not returning any data to $_POST after payment complete , but on local i am getting values in $_POST , here my return page code , i dont think its coding issue , i am using cpanel can anyone tel server configuration if required:

```
     $secretKey = "";
     print_r($_POST); //its returning array() on server and on local array( [orderId] => 1_2834_5 
     [orderAmount] => 1.00 [referenceId] => 93724505 [txStatus] => SUCCESS [paymentMode] => 
     AIRTEL_MONEY)
```

Comment: Well, then you will have to do some debugging … No one here can look into your server to see what is happening.

Comment: If you have a problem which only occurs in one specific environment, then it's usually quite difficult to spot that just by looking at the code - because the code clearly _can_ work. More likely to be a data- or configuration-related issue, neither of which you've told us anything about. And/or, there's a problem with something which is sending data to this script - so again it's outside the scope of the code you've posted. We can't really help without a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: i did but no any error found, do i need some server configuration?

Comment: after successfull payment its returning to a page i just need value in $_POST and which giving on localhost , i checked all the way but no any error , payment also success so i confused , may be i need some server configuration , anyone help please

Comment: _“i did but no any error found”_ - you did – _what_? Explain what steps you have already undertaken.

Comment: _“i have integrated cashfree payment gateway in php”_ - it is not even clear what exactly you did in those regards. Are we talking about some sort of POST request from their system to your server? (Then it would be interesting to know how you tested this on localhost to begin with, and where exactly your print_r debug output even lands.) And if that’s not it – then this should start with a proper explanation of what you are even doing.

Comment: "Explain what steps you have already undertaken"  i removed all the code and just placed print_r($_POST) and enabled error_reporting on php.ini to get errors but nothing it just print array() after successful payment , and same if i am running to local its print  "array( [orderId] => 1_2834_5 
     [orderAmount] => 1.00 [referenceId] => 93724505 [txStatus] => SUCCESS [paymentMode] => 
     AIRTEL_MONEY)" after successful payment

Comment: "it just print array()" ...this indicates that whatever is sending a POST request to your PHP script is not sending any data in the request. So you need to investigate where that came from, and why it's doing that. Again, as I said before, it's unrelated to the code you've shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you guys for all your reply, finally i found that on return page signature was not matching  its because i used http://to_return_page_link as return page url and my site has ssl so it redirects to https:// and after successful payment on return page it was not returning any data on $_post as i also used https:// on payment gateway , so as i changed http to https on code (where i mentioned return page url) its done , now working fine.